# On maven install test cases running successful but gives some warnings

Tags: java, maven, jersey

When I run maven install on my project. It gives the following warnings. Maven install is success but how should I eliminate these warnings. What dependencies should be added in order to eliminate these warnings?

```
T E S T S
Running com.test1
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 1 and column 83
log4j:WARN Document root element "log4j:configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 1 and column 83
log4j:WARN Document is invalid: no grammar found.
log4j:ERROR No appender named [CONSOLE] could be found.
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.79 sec
Running com.test2
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 1 and column 83
log4j:WARN Document root element "log4j:configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 1 and column 83
log4j:WARN Document is invalid: no grammar found.
log4j:ERROR No appender named [CONSOLE] could be found.
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.504 sec
Results :
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: You will want to post the log4j.xml file, since those warnings appear to be related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open pom.xml and remove the duplicate dependencies. See for the dependency conflicts and remove the overlapping dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

open pom.xml and remove the duplicate dependencies.